# AdMob Test ads not showing (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

i tried to use AdMob with test ads in flutter. i always receive code 3 and this two messages:

**Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.CACHE**

**Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.